# Displaying / Testing outputs are correct. Sanity Check

Tags: django

I am still learning Django and slowly improving but I have a few questions, I have my whole model below:

```
    from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Create your models here.

year_choice = [
    ('year1','1-Year'),
    ('year3','3-Year')
]
weeksinyear = 52
hours = 6.5
current_year = datetime.year


class AdminData(models.Model):
    year1 = models.IntegerField()
    year3 = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def day_rate_year1(self):
        return self.year1 / weeksinyear / hours


class Price(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contract = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=year_choice)
        start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
        end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime(2021,3,31))

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

The main concern for me at the moment is trying to understand if my function `def day_rate_year1(self):` is working correctly, if someone could point me in the right direction to understand either how I display this as a string value in a template or test in the shell to see if the value pulls through as the values for year1 and year3 can change based on user input.

I am trying to work out the day rate so I can then use the start and end dates and work out the number of days between the two to calculate a price which is then displayed to the user which can again change depending on the number of days and the contract type which is a 3 year option or 1 year option.

Let me know if you need the views or templates as well.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if someone could point me in the right direction to understand either how I display this as a string value in a template or test in the shell to see if the value pulls through as the values for year1 and year3 can change based on user input

if you launch a shell session as below, you should see the output of your property.

`python manage.py shell`

Expected output:

```py
>>> from app_name.models import AdminData
>>> test = AdminData.objects.create(year1=2010, year3=2016)
>>> print(test.day_rate_year1)
5.946745562
>>>
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple, always the case I overthink everything!! Thank you!

Comment: Don't we all. Glad to help!